# How to add a touch screen keyboard in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, on-screen-keyboard

I want to use virtual keyboardfound here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/touchscreenkeyboard.aspx 
as shown as demo i have to fix this keyboard and want to enter values many forms by keeping this keyboard in my systems home screen. i tried copying the form and pasting it is not working so please help me in this regards thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem exactly do you encounter? Do you have problems "importing" the Keybord Control? Do you problems using the Keyboard Control?

Comment: Why do you want to make your own keyboard? Windows comes with an on screen keyboard. If there is a touch device, the touch keyboard will show if needed. See [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx).

Comment: yes you are correct Nico Schertler But I wanted to make a numeric keyboard now i am done and finished that module with calling osk, thanks